# Autocomplete not working in vscode with cantools 37.2.0

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

I recently installed the cantools 37.2.0 to use it in vscode. Unfortunately the autocomplete function does not work for this library, for all other Python libraries auto completion works fine.
I installed cantools with the command

```
pip install cantools
```

I tried also to put the path in settings.json (although default Python library path which some how works for other libraries).
Installed is IntelliSense (Pylance) from Microsoft v2022.19.13251009
does someone encountered such problem with cantools library?

How to fix IntelliSense or rebuild it to see cantools library?

[image: Hitting Ctrl+Space show default Suggestions but no can tools]

[image: But for other Libs it works even without hitting Ctrl+Space]

[image: vscode console shows jupiter Erros]

Comment: So how is it not working? Why can't you elaborate on the problem? Is it difficult for you to come up with specific examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling Jupyter and reinstalling Pylance fixed the issue